# UICollectionView rendering image outside of cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with 2 cells being displayed. Each cell has a UIImageView in it. When the cells are displayed the first cell is correct but the ImageView in the second cell is being displayed as if it were in the third cell.

[image]
Code:

```
var upgradeCollectionView: UICollectionView!

lazy var upgradeView: UIView = {

    ... //Add other views

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 1, bottom: 0, right: 1)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    let itemSideSize = (self.view.frame.width - 5) / 4
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSideSize, height: itemSideSize)
    self.upgradeCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: newView.frame.width, height: newView.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    newView.addSubview(self.upgradeCollectionView)
    self.upgradeCollectionView.register(CollUpgradeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollUpgradeCell")
    self.upgradeCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.upgradeCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.upgradeCollectionView.isHidden = true
    self.upgradeCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}        

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    availableUpgrades = []
    upgrades.forEach { (upgrade) in
        if upgrade.isHidden == false{
            if upgrade.owned == false{
                availableUpgrades.append(upgrade)
            }
        }
    }

    availableUpgrades = availableUpgrades.sorted(by: { $0.cost < $1.cost })

    return availableUpgrades.count //Returns 2
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollUpgradeCell", for: indexPath) as! CollUpgradeCell
    cell.resetCell() //Resets BG color, text label, and imageview.image = nil

    let upgrade = availableUpgrades[indexPath.item]

    cell.textLabel.text = String(upgrade.cost)
    cell.imageView.image = upgrade.image
    cell.backgroundColor = .green

    return cell
}

class CollUpgradeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     var imageView = UIImageView()
     var textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 50, height: 500))

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(textLabel)
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Comment: Your cell.imageView use autolayouts? are you using constraints on it?

Comment: One suggestion whatever are you doing in `resetCell()`you can do it in `prepareForReuse()`

Comment: I've edited the question showing how I setup the ImageView in the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem, you need to use as frame of your `UIImageView` the bounds of your `CollectionViewCell`

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(textLabel)
        addSubview(imageView)
        //imageView.frame = frame  this is your problem source
        imageView.frame = self.bounds
    }
```

Hope this helps